# How to log SQLite commands in Android?

Tags: android

Im getting this error:

```
10-05 19:36:09.904: WARN/System.err(1039): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

Is there a way to the class SQLiteDatabase show queries created in insert and update methods?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably inserting two items with the same primary key, which is supposed to be unique. There is no way that I know of to get verbose SQL logs, sorry.